# I'm getting an error while building electron app in my linux Mint

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to build an electron app with electron-builder but i'm getting an error "sh: 1: build: not found...".

Im using electron 6.0.6 , with mysql , nodejs ,jquery.For a While Im trying to build this app with electron-packager and electron-builder but im getting nowhere to build a distributable package for linux and windows.

My Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "elec",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Appname",
  "author": "author <author@mail.com>",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
     "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "npm install && electron ./app",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
    "build": {
    "appId": "yourappid",
    "category": "your.app.category.type",
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "squirrel",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "ejs": "~1.0.0",
    "electron-print": "^1.0.2",
    "electron-store": "^4.0.0",
    "electron-window-manager": "^1.0.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "mysql": "github:mysqljs/mysql",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact command you are running, to generate that error message?

Comment: electron-packager . elec-meditwitt-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds

Comment: Dont You Have Any Idea Mr Cook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the command you said you use, in the comments, I think you are mixing up electron-builder and electron-packager. The latter does not need those script entries in package.json (so I don't know how that command gives the error you see).

But if you are using electron-builder, I think it is a simple copy and paste mistake. See https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide  In the scripts section, you should have:

```
  "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
  "dist": "electron-builder"
```

But you have:

```
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
```

That is why the error message is saying "build: not found."

BTW, the instructions are saying you should use `yarn dist` or `yarn pack` to run it.

Comment: Its as you said i was using packager instead of builder that was silly